# Resubmitting or Creating a Nested jQuery.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a variable in Javascript which I am trying to pass to PHP. I have this working using jQuery.post. The issue is, the variable (linkforsharedURL) is declared within a multidimensional array and the default value is immediately sent when the jQuery.post command is executed. However the value of this variable is further modified within the function, but the modified value is not sent to PHP - the original value is sent.

A solution forward I was considering was to execute another jQuery.post just after the If statement again containing the updated 'data' array - but I don't think this would be best practice.

I did consider bringing the If statement out of the jQuery.post, however the If statement is dependent on the jQuery's response variable.

My apologies for the way I have explained the above - just trying to get my head round this particular issue.

```
        // build data
        var dataURL = dataURLs[0],
            data = {
                email: email,
                name: name
                linkforsharedURL: linkforsharedURL 
            };
        
        // send data
        jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", data, function(response) {


            if (response.share_id !== undefined) {
                var pattern = new RegExp('(share_id=).*?(&|$)'), shareUrl = window.location.href;
                if (shareUrl.search(pattern) >= 0) {
                    shareUrl = shareUrl.replace(pattern, '$1' + response.share_id + '$2');
                    linkforsharedURL = shareUrl;
                    
                }
```

Comment: Upon further reflection, as the variable changes inside the jQuery post is it feasible to delay the 'jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url' command until the variable within the function has updated. The jQuery post appears to send to PHP immediately and then runs the function(response) segment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `function` to call again within jQuery.post response. try the below code.

```
// build data
var dataURL = dataURLs[0],
    data = {
        email: email,
        name: name,
        linkforsharedURL: linkforsharedURL 
    };

SendDataToPhp( data );

function SendDataToPhp(){
    // send data
    jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", data, function(response) {
        if (response.share_id !== undefined) {
            var pattern = new RegExp('(share_id=).*?(&|$)'), shareUrl = window.location.href;
            if (shareUrl.search(pattern) >= 0) {
                shareUrl = shareUrl.replace(pattern, '$1' + response.share_id + '$2');
                linkforsharedURL = shareUrl;
                data.linkforsharedURL = 'updated value to send';
                SendDataToPhp( data );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response - much appreciated. Unfortunately this seems to be duplicating the action and causing it to run twice

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: No it didn't work, as it appears that the function performs some functions at first run and then performs it again on second run. Though I am very appreciative and thankful for your suggestion.